# installing xuggler java libraries in Tomcat on Linux

Tags: linux, tomcat

I'm trying to install xuggler Java libraries in Tomcat (version 5.5) on fedora-release-7-3

Should I install the binaries available for download on xuggler website or build my own (http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/downloads/build.jsp)?

I took the easy step first and installed the readymade binaries downloaded from http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/downloads/ in usr/local/xuggler folder on my Linux server and then copied the jar files from share/java/jars folder to Tomcat's $CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib directory (as recommended by 
http://wiki.xuggle.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#I_get_an_.22UnsatisfiedLinkError.22_when_I_run_Xuggler-based_Applications_in_Tomcat
These are some 6 .jar files, including xuggle-xuggler.jar

After restarting Tomcat, I'm still getting "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle-xuggler in java.library.path" exception when my Java code attempts to invoke some xuggler method such as the one to find video duration of an flv file.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that Tomcat can see the environment variables you have to set up with XUGGLE.  In particular LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I managed to successfully install and use Xuggler. I had to eventually compile and build a version for my Linux though!

Answer (score 0):

Putting the xuggle environmental variables in the startup.sh is probably one of easiest ways to get this going. Also don't forget to put the xuggle jar only in the shared / common lib or you may run into classloader issues when you attempt to use xuggler in multiple webapps.